Azure SQL Database Login failed for user ConnectionError
Whenever i tried to connect Azure Database Table from local func using VS code I m getting this error:

originalError: ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'CloudSAa64a1c9'.
at Login7TokenHandler.onErrorMessage (/Users/yasindalkilic/Desktop/jsfunc/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/handler.js:186:19)
at Readable. (/Users/yasindalkilic/Desktop/jsfunc/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/token-stream-parser.js:19:33)

This is the function that im using fetch data from my azure database:
  const config = {
    user: 'CloudSAa64a1cd9', 
    password: '', 
    server: 'boatsaily.database.windows.net', 
    database: 'BoatSaily',
    options: {
      encrypt: true, 
      trustServerCertificate: false, 
      trustedConnection: true
    }};
  const sql = require('mssql');

 async function fetchData() {
    try {

      let pool = await sql.connect(config);
      
      let result = await pool.request().query('SELECT * FROM dbo.Kisiler');
      
      console.log(result.recordset);
      
      // Bağlantıyı kapat
      pool.close();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Hata:', err);
    }
  }
  
  fetchData();

My username and password are true. I' m very new on Azure SQL Database please help me to handle this problem.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

@ThomA Hi i edited

"trustedConnection: true" that means Windows Auth.  You need to use SQL Auth or Entra ID auth.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft I send request without trustedConnection: true but nothing change

i don't understand who give downvote this question and what his reason. I m struggling for this issue for long time. I m new and I m still learning

I found solution for who still interesting this topic. My mistake is misunderstanding of microsoft password and my SQL Server password are equal each other. That is why i took this error constantly. I reset SQL Server Password from Azure Panel then problem was solved.


Verify that SQL database authentication is enabled/allowed (the firewall is not blocking it) and that you have created a database login and user with the correct credentials.

As @david-browne-microsoft said, if you intend to authenticate using a username and password, you need to remove trustServerCertificate.

Also, if you go to the connection strings sections in the Azure Portal, you will find its connection string; this is also worth a shot


Reference:
Azure Connection Strings
SQL DB Login and User
